# Is it portable to cast the max value of a unsigned int into an int and exepect the result to be -1?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, unsigned

I've found a C++ code where we cast an unsigned int 32, initialized to its max value, into a signed int and expect it to be `-1`.
It works well on the tested compiler, but is it really portable?

```
int GetBusinessDataID()
{
    u32_t id = ~0;

    // Some code that may return a valid ID.

    return id; // Here we expect to return -1.
}
```

Comment: I think from c++20 it will be -1 since signed integers will be 2's compliment, but as of now its not guaranteed by standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is guaranteed for [integral conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) since C++20; before C++20 this is implementation-defined.

> If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type. Otherwise the result is
>
> - implementation-defined (until C++20)
> - the unique value of the destination type equal to the source value modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup>
>   where *n* is the number of bits used to represent the destination type. (since C++20).

Comment: if I understand well, since C++ 20: `int value = 0xffffffff % 2^8`, which is `0xffffffff` which is `-1` for an int

Comment: @FloFu I can't get want you mean.. For `0xffffffff % 2^8` you'll get `9`. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9MZH4Wi0Yj6dNzW0)

Comment: I was trying to understand how the conversion works. I don't understand _'the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type'_. While the value `4294967295` can't be represented in a int. It's hexadecimal value `0xffffffff` can. So, here the rule. Is it correct?

Comment: @FloFu `0xffffffff` can't either. So given `int value = 0xffffffff;`, `value` would be `-1` (since C++20). BTW: `0xffffffff` is an `unsigned int` literal itself.